# Discrepancy between UI and HTML-code Chrome & firefox & IE

Tags: html, asp.net

This code is from **inspect element** in Chrome
Watch the selectedvalue in the drop_down

```
 <td align="right">
     <input name="ctl00$MainContent$d_5km" type="text" value="110" id="MainContent_d_5km" class="vcnumbersOnly" style="padding: 0px 5px; text-align: right; width: 3em;">
 </td>
 <td class="mid">
  <select name="ctl00$MainContent$d_5ve" id="d_5ve" class="vcddl">
        <option value="-1">Kies een vestiging</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="1">Utrecht</option>
        <option value="2">Den Bosch</option>
        <option value="3">Rotterdam</option>
        <option value="4">Twente</option>
        <option value="9">Amsterdam</option>
  </select>
 </td>
```

But the screen [check DropDown as displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhQg9.png) displays: Amsterdam as selected item because that is wat was selected in the dropdown.

Also retrieving the value whilst 9 (Amsterdam) is selected on the screen gives 1 (Utrecht)

I've already checked for double ID's
tried other browsers (IE,FF) but still not working properly.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Please share the code you are using to retrieve the value.

Comment: There is no post request. Selecting the item Amsterdam doesn't really do anything. You need to use javascript to post the request of index change.

Comment: Based on @Kramb comment: Have you set "auto postback" to TRUE for the dropdown control?

Comment: Post has to be handled with javascript IIRC. The HTML control doesn't allow for Auto postback.

Comment: @ nimesh, d_5ve.selectedvalue . but nevertheless selecting 9 should be visible in the 'chrome inspect' window as being selected instead of 1. @kramb & & Nimesh : I only posted the relevant part in my Question. Ofcourse there is a postrequest otherwise i could not retreive a value at all.